# Работа с Spring Repository запрос поиска в базу

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

Использую JpaRepository в Spring.
Сделал кастомный метод для поиска.

(метод поиска)

```
@Query(value = "select b from User b where (b.name like concat('%', :name, '%'))")
List<User> findByName(@Param("name") String name);
```

С Jsp в контроллер приходит заполненный объект User, а в сервисе из него извлекается Name и передается в репозиторий, (если Name не был введен то приходит "" а не null и проблем нет).

(Сервис)

```
public List<User> findByName(User user) {
return userDAO.findByName(user.getName());
}
```

Проблема в том, что как только я захотел добавить в метод возможность поиска по возрасту и ИД то вылетает NullPointer. Потому что если пользователь не ввел возраст или ИД то в сервисе уже возникакеn NPE. А если null отловить в сервисе то что тогда передать в репозиторий что бы данное нулл поле не учитывалось в поиске?

(Метод поиска с добавленными полями)

```
@Query(value = "select b from User b where b.name like concat('%', :name, '%') and b.age = :age and b.id = :id")
List<User> findByName(@Param("name") String name, @Param("age") int age, @Param("id") int id);
```

Так же сейчас если даже все поля заполнить то ничего не находит, хотя заполняю правильно..

Или может вообще поиск по другому надо делать?

Answer (score 1):

Данную проблему можно решить с помощью Спецификаций
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications
и переопределяя метод toPredicate учесть все необходимые условия

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае лучше, конечно же, разделить эти случаи (у вас ведь сервис называется  `findByName` - пусть и выполняет именно эти обязанности).

Если же вам по каким то религиозным причинам делать этого нельзя - то конструируйте запрос отдельно на основании *не-пустых* значений параметров.

Comment: Да при чем тут религиозным, просто хотелось сделать метод который сможет искать по одному полю и по нескольким. А так придется сделать только 3 метода отдельных для 3 полей. Потому что если еще и для нескольких такие делать то надо учитывать все комбинации ж. Например первый есть двух нету\первого нету 2 есть и так далее..

Comment: Прочитайте статью http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/j-genericdao/, а также посмотрите на паттерн Repository. В текущем варианте вам придется избавится от аннотации Query - запрос надо будет строить вручную, а также добавлять в него именнованные параметры на каждый входной параметр метода (само собой, это будет делаться в цикле по всем входным параметрам. Будет там проверка на null или ещё что то - решать уже вам).